# Horizontal list or a list that you can swipe through based upon size of viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to create a website where there is a horizontal list. In the normal viewport I want them grouped next to each other but as soon as the viewport hits a certain threshold I want the list to become a carousel. Is this possible? I've been searching for a possible solution the past hours and couldn't find anything fitting my needs.

Picture below demonstrates what I need it to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XqZI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to query the viewport size and then load a function that animates them if you are at one of the smaller sizes.

It'd involve some CSS along the lines of taking your elements that are say floated (`float:left;` etc.) and absolutely positioning them so they are all in the same place - you could then crossfade if you wanted. Another way would be to have them come in from off the visible area.

Then at smaller sizes you would just need to call your carousel function to change the CSS of the page and a function to animate it.

Comment: Thank you kindly. That should help me get started.

Comment: For an audio player rather than a carousel I've done the same recently and it worked great. Give it a try (and if it works for you I'd appreciate you accepting the answer - cheers!).